# Tortoisehg: how to revert subfolders to revision

Tags: tortoisehg

I would like to revert only some subfolders (and all their descendants) of my repository to a certain revision.
Does anybody know if it is possible to do it with TortoisHg (without having to select each single file)?

Note: I'm using TortoiseHg, version 2.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can most easily do this from the `manifest` window in TortoiseHg.

In TortoiseHg Workbench, select `View -> Manifest` (Shortcut `Alt-3` for me), select the revision you want, and in the manifest window right-click in the folder in question and select `Revert to Revision...`.

You can bring up the manifest tool directly from the command line with:

```
thg manifest -r REV
```

Where `REV` is the revision you want to revert to.  But if you're happy using the command line, you can save some time by just doing the following:

```
hg revert -r REV folder_to_revert
```

After you've done this, just commit the local changes (the result of reverting files) however you normally do it.  If you decide against reverting the files, just do a clean update.

Answer (score -1):

1. Checkout trunk into a working copy with depth = "Only this item"
2. Open working copy
3. Go to repo browser from the working copy
4. Select your desired project subfolder(s), right-click and select "Update item to revision"

This will pull only the subfolder(s) you've selected into your working copy.

Comment: That sounds suspiciously like the Subversion way of doing things, especially specifying the depth, and making reference to only pulling selected subfolders. That's not generally the way Mercurial (and hence TortoiseHg) works.